# Passing function as parameter to other function

Tags: python

This is the exercise:

> (a) The function takes another function f (n) with n ∈ N as parameter
>   and returns the limit of the row. The function uses an epsilon as
>   before, but this time the loop will end when the difference between f
>   (n) and f (n + 1) is smaller than epsilon.

(It's not for points, just for exercising).

This is my code:

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(10000000)

epsilon = 0.0001
def limit(param):
    while param(1) >= epsilon:
        print(param)

    return -1


def f(n):
    return f(n / (n + 1))


limit(f)
```

I have to make a function `limit` which takes other functions as parameter. Those functions create rows: e.g:

```
f(n) = n / (n + 1)
g(n) = n / (n + 2)
h(n) = n * 0.005
```

The function limit needs to be able to take all of those functions as a parameter and than to check if that function converges to one (done with the epsilon).

I know how to test if a specific row converges to one:

```
epsilon = 0.0001
def test(n):
    while abs(n / (n + 1) -1) >= epsilon:
        n += 1
        print(n, "/", n+1, " = ", n/(n+1))

    return True

test(1)
```

But I encounter the following problems in my first code:

- How to pass the function (e.g f(n)) to limit and being able to use parameters
- How to use n as parameter for f in the function limit
- ...

Any help in general would be welcome!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the function and its parameters as separate parameters and then create the function call inside the function.

Okay, that's a confusing statement. :-)

Let me clarify with a code example:

```
def function(parameter):
    print(f'I am function function with parameter {parameter}')

def call_me_with(func, param):
    func(param)

call_me_with(function, 5)
```

Functions are objects in Python, just like (almost) anything else.

Hope this helps!

Comment: In fact, `func` can be any object at all, as long as its type has a `__call__` method. You can have callable classes, etc.

Answer (score 0):

you could for instance use what's referred to as dependency injection by just passing the name of your function as a parameter and calling it inside your function like you would have out of it
for example

```
def limit(param, function, n):
    while param(1) >= epsilon:
        print(param)
        result = function(n)
    return -1
```